# Windows Batch to concatenate Files in Subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file

currently I try to concatenate txt files in subdirectories with this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "sourcedir=Sourcedir" 
SET "destdir=Outputdir"
MD "%destdir%">NUL 2>nul

for /D %%J in ("%Csourcedir%\*") do (
    > "%destdir%\%%~nxJ_merge.txt" (
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('
            dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "%%~J\*.txt" ^| findstr /V /I /C:"merge.txt"
        ') do (
            type "%%~J\%%I"
        )
    )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The issue is my folder structure, for which I can not find a appropriate wildcard:

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Output\This is what I want to wildcard\sections_text

SO basically I have many different named folders, but which all contain a subdirectory called sections_text

Is there a way to wildcard this, or to "pull" all files one level up?

Comment: Your intent is unclear. There is a stray `C` in `%sourcedir%`. Do you want to move all files in `C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Output\*\sections_text` to `C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Output\*` ?

Comment: Yes you are exactly right!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /D %%J in ("%sourcedir%\*") do (
  ECHO MOVE "%%J\sections_text\*" "%%J"
)
```

Where `sourcedir` is set to `C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Output`

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)